# Trying to interact with HTML page elements, but none of them are found

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-webdriver-python

I'm trying to scrape a webpage using Selenium, but when I try to pass the XPath of a button, I get an error saying that this element does not exist. I tried with another website, and it worked perfectly. I also tried using Puppeteer, but encountered the same problem. When I do $('.selector') for the button I'm trying to click in the page console, it returns an object x.fn.init [prevObject: x.fn.init(1)]. I don't know how to use this to interact with the element itself, but I believe the issue revolves around this.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://senamhi.gob.bo/index.php/sysparametros')
open_window_elem = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="myModal"]/div/div/div')
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_by_offset(500, 200)    
action.click()
action.perform()
y_coordinate = open_window_elem.location["y"]
x_coordinate = open_window_elem.location["x"]
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_by_offset(x_coordinate, y_coordinate)
action.click()
action.perform()
sleep(20)
driver.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/app-root/app-public-template/app-public-base/app-public-stations-info-export/div/div/div/div[2]/button').click()
```

The part of clicking somewhere on the screen is working, as when I enter the page, there appears to be a pop-up that requires clicking somewhere to dismiss. Then, a screen with a button comes up that I'm not able to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in HTML the element that you want to click is inside `object` element.

Before interacting with any element inside `object` or `iframe` you need to instruct selenium to switch to that object, interact with the element that you want to interact with, and then switch back to the default context.

```py
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element("xpath", "//object"))

driver.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/app-root/app-public-template/app-public-base/app-public-stations-info-export/div/div/div/div[2]/button').click()

driver.switch_to.default_content()
```