# Selenium – can't click() on this site's pop-up button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, popup

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.chefkoch.de/')
WebDriverWait(browser, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(text(),'Akzeptieren und weiter')]"))).click()
```

presence_of_element_located instead of clickable, by CSS_SELECTOR, the actual XPATH or the actual XPATH in it's full length, none of it works.

I just want to click() on the left button of that first appearing pop-up.

**EDIT**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get('https://www.chefkoch.de/')

WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@id='sp_message_iframe_847995']")))
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//button[text()='Zustimmen'])[1]"))).click()
browser.switch_to.default_content()

WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="w-header"]/div[1]/div/div[2]'))).click()
```

So far so good...
here comes the next overlay. This one does not appear to be an iframe, and again no matter what I've tried, can't interact with anything on/in this container

The input field is of interest to me

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77197020/trying-to-interact-with-html-page-elements-but-none-of-them-are-found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is the button you want to click:

[image]

You need to switch into the `IFRAME` first before performing `click()` on the button. Refer the below working code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get('https://www.chefkoch.de/')

# Switch into the IFRAME
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@id='sp_message_iframe_847995']")))

# Click on Zustimmen button
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//button[text()='Zustimmen'])[1]"))).click()

# Come out of IFRAME
browser.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now I know how to handle iframes. I'm already working on the next issue, which is in the edit